# Convert a stack trace to a value

Tags: stack-trace, ceylon

I want to get `Throwable.getStackTrace()` result as a value in Ceylon. Java interface has [printStackTrace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter)) method with parameter [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), but Ceylon Throwable interface has not. How can i get it?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by converting the stack trace to a value. If my answer isn't what you're looking for, please clarify your question and let me know.

Comment: Your answer is ok. I didn't know the top-level function about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to [`java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(PrintWriter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace-java.io.PrintWriter-), Ceylon's language module has the top-level function [`void printStackTrace(Throwable, Anything(String))`](http://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.1.0/module-doc/api/index.html#printStackTrace). You provide the exception and a function which accepts a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no true equivalent of Java's `Throwable.getStackTrace()` in the Ceylon language module because we wouldn't be able to implement that operation in JavaScript.

Therefore, I've just added the `javaStackTrace()` function to the module `ceylon.interop.java`, and that will be available in the 1.2 release of the platform.

(As already answered by @gdejohn, there's also the `printStackTrace()` function in `ceylon.language`.)